# Strange behavior on GROUP BY and LIKE?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Below is simplified example of my data. As you can see – there are just two rows here

[image]

So I run below and suddenly getting unexpected result

[image]

What I expected was something like:

[image]

> Why am I getting wrong result?

Moreover, when I run below – I am getting only one row. Why second row with `id=1` is not showing??

[image]

> Is there BigQuery bug or what?

*Disclaimer*: *I was asked exactly this type of question few times offline (outside of StackOverflow) and recently saw very same question on SO ([I can't understand this BigQuery magic. find string with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453064/i-cant-understand-this-bigquery-magic-find-string-with-like)) but unfortunately it was deleted so I decided to Post this on my own*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `GROUP BY` not grouping those two rows is that `str` field in those rows are actually different. Unfortunately, BigQuery Web UI collapses spaces in result panel when it is in `Table` mode. To see real/original values you can switch to `JSON mode`, as below

[image]

Same reason is for unexpected result for use of `LIKE`

As of how to deal with this? It depends!
For example you can kind of normalize your strings by suppressing spaces by yourself as it is shown below

[image]

*P.S. In our internal tools – we just fixed the issue with suppressed spaces and just simply show all spaces:*

[image]